# Xcode5 build universal app for iPhone in iPad store

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode4, xcode5

I found a problem with my build, looks like Xcode5 changed this in comparing to Xcode4.

before, in Xcode4: I choose to build "universal" app and my app with iPhone size is scaled on iPad, can be found both in iPhone and iPad store.

now, in Xcode5: if I choose "universal", my app with iPhone size is no longer scaled on iPad, but keeps the original size while leaving the whole right part empty. If I choose "iPhone", it is scaled on iPad, but can no longer be found in iPad store.

I noticed UIDeviceFamily is removed from Info.plist in Xcode5

what I want is simply the same build result with Xcode5 for my app as with Xcode4. Anyone has any idea about it?

Here's my code to initiate the root view in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

DialoguesVC* dvc = [[DialoguesVC alloc] init];
HomeVC* hvc = [[HomeVC alloc] initWithRootViewController:dvc];
[self.window setRootViewController:hvc];
```

HomeVC is a UINavigationViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 5 requires that a separate storyboard for iPhone and iPad is defined in the target for your universal app. You can however select the same one if you like. Here's how to do it:

1. In the Project Navigator on the left, select the bug blue bar at the top with your Project Name in it.
2. On the right, select your target from the drop down menu. This is where you define if your app is iPhone, iPad or Universal. In your case, select Universal (under Deployment Info).
3. You should now see two tabs in the same section: iPhone and iPad. Switch between them to define allowed orientations, Status Bar Style and - most importantly - select which Storyboard you're using for each device.

That should do the trick, and when run on an iPad, it should now load the iPhone storyboard as Xcode 4 would have done.

This may not look as attractive as you would hope - in which case you can copy your iPhone Storyboard and make changes specifically for iPad. I've explained how to do this here: http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-convert-your-iphone-storyboard-into-an-ipad-storyboard/

Comment: Hi Jay, thank you for your answer! that should be but the problem with me is that I don't use storyboard. I got too many views to organize so I'm sticking to the old xib files. And I don't have a "main interface" to fill there. Do you have a solution in this case?

Comment: and I create a new project with storyboard to test your solution. Sadly it's not working, the view still get fit to iPad, not scaled to iPad screen.

Comment: Ah OK - in that case your main view is loaded under applicationDidFinishLaunching. Could you post that method so I can have a look?

Comment: Hi Jay, see the edited question. Would be great if you could figure out a solution.